# Finding the norm of functional $f(u)=\int_0^{1/2} u(t)\,dt$ on Sobolev space $W^{2,1}[0,1]$.

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

> Compute the norm of functional $f\in (W^{2,1}[0,1])^*$ given by $$f(u)=\int_0^{1/2} u(t)\,dt.$$

**My attempt**
The norm of $f$ is computed by
\begin{align}
\|f\|=\sup_{u\ne 0} \frac{f(u)}{\|u\|_{W^{1,2}[0,1]}}.
\end{align}
Since
\begin{align}
f(u)\le \int_0^1|u(t)|\,dt\le \|u\|_{W^{1,2}[0,1]}
\end{align}
we know $\|f\|\le 1$. Then I guess $\|f\|=1$ and want to find a $u$ such that
\begin{align}
 \|u\|_{W^{1,2}[0,1]} = \int_0^{1/2}u(t)dt.
\end{align}
But I met some problem. Naively I want to set
$$
u(t)=\begin{cases}
1 & 0\le t\le 1/2;\\
0 & 1/2< t\le 1.
\end{cases}
$$
But it doesn't satisfy $u\in W^{2,1}[0,1]$. Then I want to construct a smooth $u$ such that $u\equiv 1$ on $[0,1/2]$ and $u\equiv 0$ on $[1/2+\epsilon,1]$. But I found that
$$
\int_0^1|u'(t)|dt\ge u(1)-u(0)=1.
$$
So this also fails.

Now I guess $\|f\|\ne 1$, and I got stuck on the precise computation. Any helps? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I thought I found it out. Set $u\equiv 1$ we know $\|f\|\le 1/2$.
Then we show $\|f\|=1/2$. By density, it suffices to show that
$$
\int_0^{1/2}u(t)\,dt\le\frac12\|u\|_{W^{1,2}[0,1]}\quad\forall u\in C^\infty(0,1).\quad (*)
$$
Set $m=\inf_{(0,1)}|u|$ and $M=\sup_{(0,1)}|u|$.
Since
$$
u(x_1)-u(x_2)=\int_{x_1}^{x_2}u'(t)\,dt\le \int_0^1|u'(t)|\,dt
$$
we easily know
$$
M-m\le \|u'\|_{L^1[0,1]}.
$$
Then
$$
\|u\|_{L^1[0.5,1]}+\|u'\|_{L^1[0,1]}\ge \frac12m+(M-m)\ge \frac12M\ge \|u\|_{L^1[0,0.5]}
$$
and hence
$$
\|u\|_{W^{1,2}[0,1]}\ge \|u\|_{L^1[0,0.5]}+\|u\|_{L^1[0.5,1]}+\|u'\|_{L^1[0,1]}
\ge 2\|u\|_{L^1[0,0.5]}
\ge 2\int_0^{1/2}u(t)\,dt.
$$
Hence we get $(*)$, which complete the proof of $\|f\|=1/2$.

Comment: In the question and answer you mix $W^{2,1}$ and $W^{1,2}$. Which do you mean? The estimates are done in $W^{1,1}$, though.